# How to share link that opens an app [Swift]

Tags: swift

In my app I've a share button.

```
    let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [], applicationActivities: nil)
    activityVC.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = view
    self.present(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

How can I share a link that opens the app?

Comment: You mean in another application you need to have a button that opens your application ?

Comment: Look up "URL schemes". Those might be useful.

Comment: Yes, for example I send via message the link of my app.

Answer (score 1):

As someone mentioned above you can achieve that by using URL schemes, with this you can open your app from links you define. The following documentation shows how to do this:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/core_app/allowing_apps_and_websites_to_link_to_your_content/defining_a_custom_url_scheme_for_your_app

However, Apple recommend that you achieve the above using Universal Links instead. If you own a domain/website then the below process is the preferred option and means your app will automatically open when a user clicks a link to your website, instead of opening Safari etc

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/core_app/allowing_apps_and_websites_to_link_to_your_content

Hope one of those is helpful!